# How to combine a number of screens into a single display in gtk

Tags: gtk, gdk

I have a problem where i am supposed to export the display to many other screens where those screens form a part of a single display( ie many screens combine to make a single display). I know i have to use GdkScreen for it but i still dont kno how to. Can anyone please give me an example or an explanation or guide me to a related tutorial for it? How do i export the display to other systems?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, this isn't something GTK would do, it's something you would configure when setting up the X server. The feature is called Xinerama (among other names).

Look for stuff under preferences called Monitors or Display or things like that. It depends on your Linux distribution and video drivers.